# Will GCM work in a normal HTML+JavaScript page?

Tags: chrome-gcm

I know the GCM push notification works inside a Google Chrome Extension/App and I tested it and working fine.

But, will Google Push Notification work on in a normal HTML+Javascript page without any extension programming?

Answer (score 1):

No need to create Google Chrome Extension/App for GCM push notification for chrome. Check out following links for more details:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en
https://simple-push-demo.appspot.com/

Comment: ya, I know this, but is really unfortunate that a Service Worker Push will only work with a properly SSL certified web. In case if there is an internal web network through which If I want to implement a self-signed certificate, then I have to pass many command line arguments to google chrome browser to make it unsecure

Comment: yeah! service worker push need https enabled web only but for development purpose its exempt localhost.